How to Ensure Correct Alternation Between Addition and Subtraction in DFS for Matrix Traversal?
I'm working on a DFS algorithm to traverse an 8x8 matrix where I need to alternate between addition and subtraction while updating the maximum values for each cell. But it is not working as I want it to work.
This is the problem I am trying to solve:

You are given a classic chess board. Each cell has a non-negative integer. The king is located in the bottom-left cell. He can move up, right, or diagonally up and right. Two players take turns. The game ends when the king comes to the right-top cell. The player who moves gets money from the other player. The amount of money is the number in the cell, where the move was ended. You need to find the value of the game. The value of the game is the amount of money that the first player will have at the end of the game. First player tries to maximize the value, while second player tries to minimize it.
Input
Eight lines, each of them contains eight non-negative integers. Each integer is less than 1000. The number in the left-bottom cell always is 0.
Output
The value of the game.
Sample input 1:
0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

Sample output 1:
4

This is the algorithm I have come up with, I added is_first_player variable, but I don't quite understand why subtraction doesn't work.

def dfs_matrix_max_sum(matrix):
    n = len(matrix)
    max_sum_matrix = [[-sys.maxsize] * n for _ in range(n)]  
    visited = set()
    
    def is_valid(x, y):
        return 0 <= x < n and 0 <= y < n
    
    def dfs(x, y, current_sum, is_first_player):
        if not is_valid(x, y) or (x, y) in visited:
            return
        
        visited.add((x, y))
        
        if is_first_player:
            current_sum += matrix[x][y]  # First player adds
        else:
            current_sum -= matrix[x][y]  # Second player subtracts
        
        # Update the cell with the maximum sum encountered so far
        if current_sum > max_sum_matrix[x][y]:
            max_sum_matrix[x][y] = current_sum
            
            # Define directions: right, diagonally upright, up
            directions = [(0, 1), (-1, 1), (-1, 0)]
            
            for dx, dy in directions:
                new_x, new_y = x + dx, y + dy
                dfs(new_x, new_y, current_sum, not is_first_player)
        
        visited.remove((x, y))
    
    dfs(7, 0, 0, True)
    
    return max_sum_matrix

matrix = [
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]
]

result = dfs_matrix_max_sum(matrix)

for row in result:
    print(row)

Result:
[3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6]
[3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6]
[2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5]
[2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5]
[1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4]
[1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4]
[0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3]
[0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3]

The algorithm should correctly alternate between addition and subtraction as it traverses the matrix, and each cell in max_sum_matrix should reflect the maximum value possible for that cell. There are multiple paths for a given cell from the start position and each path results in different sum. Among these sums, the cell should contain the max one.
How can I ensure that the alternation between addition and subtraction works correctly?
Are there any issues with my current approach, and how can I address them?

I don't think it's enough to track only max_sum_matrix[x][y] for each row/column x and y, since player two's objective is to minimize the value of the game. If you add in a second two-dimensional array and update/use that simulates player two's objective you should be good to go.

The problem is that you always maximise a cell's result, while the opponent would do all to minimise it. So if the opponent finds a move that decreases it, you should also keep track of that, since it is a starting point for the next move of the maximising player.
This means you need to track two scores for each cell, depending who played last to reach that cell. The next player should take the best score at the starting-cell (of the considered move) from the viewpoint of the opponent, and then aim to get the best result among the three possible moves.
Also be aware that DFS is not so efficient for this type of problem: it will continue to pursue paths, possibly until the end, even if later on it turns out that half-way that path, there was a more optimal route to get to that cell -- invalidating all the work that was already done beyond that point.
A row by row incremental approach (dynamic programming, akin to a BFS approach) is more suitable for this problem.
Here is a possible implementation:
def matrix_max_sum(matrix):
    prev_row = []
    for row in reversed(matrix):
        curr_row = []
        for c, money in enumerate(row):
            if c:  # Not left-most column
                if prev_row:  # Not left-most column & not bottom row
                    mini, maxi = (  # Three possible moves: take best (for both players)
                        max(prev_row[c][0], prev_row[c-1][0], curr_row[-1][0]),
                        min(prev_row[c][1], prev_row[c-1][1], curr_row[-1][1])
                    )
                else:  # Not left-most column, but bottom row
                    mini, maxi = curr_row[-1]
            elif prev_row:  # Left-most column, but not bottom row
                mini, maxi = prev_row[c]
            else:  # Bottom-left corner cell
                mini, maxi = 0, 0
            # Add the money to the best source cell, from viewpoint of opponent
            curr_row.append((money + maxi, money + mini))
        prev_row = curr_row

    # We have a score for when player 1 or 2 makes last move: get best of both
    return max(prev_row[-1])

